# How do you estimate the mean (average) of a histogram?

Tags: statistics

I have some trouble finding tutorials of this topic.  I understand that estimating the mean from a histogram is only an estimate, however, is there some sort of formula or process to acquire the mean?

Comment: The same way you estimate them if the values were displayed normally rather than as a histogram.  For mean and median you just get a feel for it and try to guesstimate a number "somewhere in the middle."  For mode, that is simply the most frequently occurring number.  Be aware though that unless the values are labeled in a histogram, mode can be quite tricky.  Imagine a histogram with the values $4,5,6,100,200,200$.  It might look like there are three fives at a glance rather than the three small numbers all being different which would make your guess at a mode incorrect.

Comment: http://www.cs.uni.edu/~campbell/stat/histrev2.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking an example from [Wikipedia's histogram article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram), you might see something the following histogram

[image: histogram]

and you might guess a mean around $25$ (between the fifth and sixth bins) which has most of the data to the left, but counterbalanced by the more extreme values to the right

If you wanted the precise figure, you might look at the location and dimension of each bin.  In this example, Wikipedia actually gives numbers, so let's use those

```
Bin-left    Bin-width   Bin-height
 0           5           836
 5           5          2737
10           5          3723
15           5          3926
20           5          3596
25           5          1438
30           5          3273
35           5           642
40           5           824
45          15           613
60          30           215
90          60            57
```

But to find the mean (the average moment or leverage about $0$) you need to know the area of each bin (width times height) and the midpoint of each bin, in order to multiply these together to give the leverage

```
Bin-left    Bin-width  Bin-height      Bin-area        Bin-midpoint     Bin-leverage

 0           5           836             4180             2.5                10450.0
 5           5          2737            13687             7.5               102652.5
10           5          3723            18618            12.5               232725.0
15           5          3926            19634            17.5               343595.0
20           5          3596            17981            22.5               404572.5
25           5          1438             7190            27.5               197725.0
30           5          3273            16369            32.5               531992.5
35           5           642             3212            37.5               120450.0
40           5           824             4122            42.5               175185.0
45          15           613             9200            52.5               483000.0
60          30           215             6461            75.0               484575.0
90          60            57             3435           120.0               412200.0
```

Adding up the areas to give $124089$ and the leverages to give $3488122.5$ and dividing the former by the latter gives a mean of about $28.2$

This might be a slight over estimate (a) because people tend to answer survey questions with round numbers so more to the left than to the right of these bins and (b) because among the extreme values on the right smaller values may be more likely than larger values, i.e. the bins may not actually be rectangles.  Even ignoring those points, this calculated mean and the original guess of $25$ are not far apart

Answer (score 1):

Suppose (for example) that your histogram shows the weights of people in kilograms. The histogram has 3 columns -- one for people who weigh 50 to 60 kg, one for people who weigh 60 to 70 kg, and one for people who weigh 70 to 80 kg. Suppose the first column has height 2, the second column has height 3, and the third has height 1. In summary we have

```
Weight 50 to 60   --  column height = 2
Weight 60 to 70   --  column height = 3
Weight 70 to 80   --  column height = 1
```

If we don't have any further info, it's reasonable to assume that the two people in the 50-to-60 category both weigh 55 kg (the average of 50 and 60).

Continuing this approach, we assume that our 6 people have weights 55, 55, 65, 65, 65, 75.

I expect you know how to compute the mean of those 6 numbers.

Comment: Thank you for the answer!